# Issue with getting started with beagle bone, cant access 192.168.7.2

Tags: backbone.js, beagleboard, beagleboneblack

I just started with the beaglebone and I have no prior knowledge of 
 programming. I tried to  follow this  link" http://beagleboard.org/Getting%20Started".  In the initial steps after installing the drivers, i fail in the STEP 3 : when i try to connect to 192.168.7.2( i typed the same in the url) , I get the following error **The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: "http ://192.168.7.2/ " Access Denied.  Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.  Your cache administrator is** ....... 
 I read that this step is important to get access to the browser on the board ? if so what should i do?  kindly help!!
regards

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your browser cache. By the message you've received, it can be a problem with your firewall also, you should disable it and try to reconnect to the bbb.

Regards,